# HttpPostedFileBase method not being found

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my view model I've added an `HttpPostedFileBase` object as a property. On my part of my view, I want people to be able to select a file from anywhere on our LAN and be able to upload a spreadsheet for processing.

The page as I have it written write now posts back to the correct controller method as long as no file has been selected. However, if I select a spreadsheet to send back to the controller I get the page displayed below from Chrome. I've set a breakpoint in the controller just to verify, and it only gets hit if I do not select a file. 
[image]

**ViewModel**

```
namespace Monet.ViewModel
{

    public class ZipCodeIndex 
    {
        //Imported spreadsheet
        [DisplayName("Import Spreadsheet")]
        public HttpPostedFileBase Import { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
@model  Monet.ViewModel.ZipCodeIndex

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Zip Code Territory Search";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "ZipCodeTerritory", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    <div style="float: right; padding-left: 15px;">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Import, new { type = "file" })
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Spreadsheet" />            
    </div>
}
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadFile(ZipCodeIndex index)
    {
        //Set a breakpoint here that only gets hit if file isn't selected
        var fp = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/ImportUploads"), Path.GetFileName(index.Import.FileName));

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

**EDIT**

I altered the form to simply pass the file back to the controller. However, I'm still encountering the exact same issue. Using the code below the site will post back to the controller if there is not file selected. However, if a file is selected I receive the "webpage is not available" message (get this using Chrome, IE 10, and Firefox).

**View**

```
using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "ZipCodeTerritory", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    <div style="float: right; padding-left: 15px;">
        <input type="file" name="FileUpload1" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Spreadsheet" />            
    </div>
}
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase Import)
    {
        //Set a breakpoint here that only gets hit if file isn't selected
        var fp = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/ImportUploads"), Path.GetFileName(Import.FileName));

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Here is a screenshot of the Network tab in the Developer Tools

[image]

**SECOND EDIT**

Ok, so I have found that any of the methods posted either in my post or below actually work as long as I'm not grabbing the spreadsheet I need... I grabbed a simple text file and was able to post the file back to the controller just fine. Next I tried a file a little bit bigger, and bigger until I went for the spreadsheet that I need for this page (the spreadsheet has 100k records in it). Once I got to the spreadsheet I received the "Webpage is not available" message again.

Is there a file size limit when using an `HttpPostedFileBase` and if so is there a way to alter it, say in the web.config?

The spreadsheet I will typically need is going to be around 9/10 MB large.

Comment: Are you using any custom model binders?

Comment: No, just what you see in the post.

Comment: Same issue with Firefox?

Comment: Yup, same issue with Firefox, Chrome, and IE10.

Comment: Whats happening in Developer Tools (F12)? Specifically under the Network tab.

Comment: Just added to the post. Not sure if that's helpful or not but that's what comes up when I receive the "Webpage not found" message

Comment: Yea that helps, I added a possible answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try increasing the MaxRequestLength size, add this to your web.config under the `<system.web>` section.

```
 <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
```

Add the attribute if the 'httpRuntime' element already exists. Can read more about [this here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can embed the `HttpPostedFileBase` in a view model, but I am fairly certain that you cannot use this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => mode.Import, new { type = "file" })
```

Instead, you have to use an `input type="file"` and name it the same thing as the controller expects:

```
<input type="file" name="Import" />
```

If it still doesn't bind, I would take it out of the view model and change your POST action to something like the following:

```
public ActionResult UploadFile(ZipCodeIndex index, HttpPostedFileBase import)
```

Again, I don't know if you can bind `HttpPostedFileBase` within a view model, but I do know that the second method works as long as you name your `input` element the same as your parameter is named.

Comment: You can bind `HttpPostedFileBase` in a model, I do it all the time.

Comment: You can embed `HttpPostedFileBase` in a viewmodel and it will work. Also TextBoxFor helper method will render the relevant HTML markup for this need (input type="file" />)

Answer (score 0):

Is your `UploadFile` action method is in `ZipCodeTerritory` controller (`ZipCodeTerritoryController.cs`) ? If yes, This should work.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "YourControllerNameHere",
                      FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
     //your code 
}
```

One reason you may get the "Page not found" could be, you do not have the Index action in your current controller (`ZipCodeTerritoryController`) to which you are redirecting the user.

Comment: Yes, that's correct about the controller name. However, unless I'm missing something that's exactly what I have: `Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "ZipCodeTerritory", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })`

Comment: What does the signature of yhour controller method look like?

Comment: Also, the index action is in the same controller. For whatever reason, I can post to this method if there is no file selected. However once the file is selected it won't work.